# How to save cookies in CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm new to CefSharp. Last week i build my first little program with CefSharp in C#. It's a split screen program.
In one split i loaded Tweetdeck. It works fine, but Tweetdeck doesn't store cookies. Every time i start the program, i must login.
Is there a way to save the cookies?

```
var browser1 = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/")
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        };
splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(browser1);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set CefSettings.CachePath directory. Settings are passed to Cef.Initialize().

Comment: can you add more more details how to use it

Comment: @shyam_ Example code here: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/5248174f894cba94c11bdf4aefe6b74383326d6c/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L51

Answer (score 19):

just on how to use it.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            CefSharp.CefSettings settings = new CefSharp.CefSettings();
            settings.CachePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\CEF"; 
           CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);

            InitializeComponent();
            //webcontrol.BrowserSettings.ApplicationCache = CefSharp.CefState.Enabled;

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should ideally use a separate folder for cache directory

Comment: I have suggested an edit as using the chrome cache folder is problematic at best. You would likely have problems running them at the same time and when Google updates to a newer version it will potentially break if you have a version mismatch with CefSharp being older.

Comment: Now this class is in a different namespace: `CefSharp.WinForms.CefSettings`