# How to save cookies in CefSharp WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, cefsharp

I need WPF CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser to save cookies. I've found similar question but for Winforms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419483/how-to-save-cookies-in-cefsharp). The problem is that Cef.Initialize() is called in ChromiumWebBrowser so I don't have access to it.

How this can be done in wpf cef sharp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just need to do this earlier in App.xaml.cs like in this example:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf/App.xaml.cs

Comment: For clarity, the `Cef.Initialize()` call in the `ChromiumWebBrowser` constructor is there as a fallback, if you make the call yourself it will be ignored.

A slightly more detailed example can be found at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/41/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L82