# CefSharp how to store cookies

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I can't get cookies to save in CefSharp.

Here is what I tried:

```
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
        settings.RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088;
        settings.CachePath = path;
```

I'm using the desktop just to test it but I tried others as well.

This is the solution others got but I can't get it to work:
Set `CefSettings.CachePath` directory. Settings are passed to `Cef.Initialize()`. The answer was from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419483/how-to-save-cookies-in-cefsharp?noredirect=1&lq=1).

After the comments I have tried this:

In the Initialize part I put this

```
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        settings.RemoteDebuggingPort = 8088;
        settings.CachePath = path;
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
```

and

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SearchBox.Text = "http://www.google.com/";
        chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(SearchBox.Text);
        this.MainBrowser.Controls.Add(chrome);
        chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        chrome.AddressChanged += Chrome_AddressChanged;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save cookies in CefSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419483/how-to-save-cookies-in-cefsharp)

Comment: That's the solution I saw but I can't get it working.

Comment: Alright I am sorry for that. But did you try debugging or anything yet? Also, try and place `settings` in the arguement of `Cef.Initialize();` and see if it works first.

Comment: Set the properties, then call Initialize.

Comment: I still can't get it working. I'm not very good at this but I've read everything online and I'm doing something wrong. I will edit my question and show what I done

Comment: Take a few hours away from the problem, then come back and look at your code again. Try explaining your code to yourself or someone else, your mistake is blatantly obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        private void InitializeChromium()
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        settings.RemoteDebuggingPort = 8080;
        settings.CachePath = path;

        //Initialize Cef with the provided settings
        Cef.Initialize(settings);


        //Create a browser component
        chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(SearchBox.Text);

        //Add he browser to the form
        this.MainBrowser.Controls.Add(chrome);
        //Make the browser fill the form
        chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

Comment: I solved it by starting the initialisation from scratch and going through everything slowly